# Python - Using bs4 for nested html tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to print the words USA and Canada from this HTML code:

```html
<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
    <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=us&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">USA</a>
    <span class="ghost">|</span>
    <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=ca&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">Canada</a>
</div>
```

How can I get the words with bs4? I googled it but I found nothing useful.

Comment: What precisely have you tried, and what is the problem with it? If the answer, as seems likely, is "nothing", then go away and change that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your bs4 code?

Answer (score 0):

if this is all you have you can use get_text for each a tag.
please try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
        <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=us&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">USA</a>
              <span class="ghost">|</span>
        <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=ca&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">Canada</a>
    </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
[atag.get_text() for atag in soup.find_all('a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text, the following code will work :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_string = """<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
        <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=us&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">USA</a>
              <span class="ghost">|</span>
        <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=ca&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">Canada</a>
    </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
print([node.string for node in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"itemprop" : "url"})] )
```

The above code will result in :

```
[u'USA', u'Canada']
```

You can refer to BeautifulSoup [Documentation here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Its is very easy to use and straight forward.

Also, you use do this with the help of **lxml** which is order of magnitude faster than BeautifulSoup.

```
from lxml import html
html_string = """<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
        <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=us&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">USA</a>
              <span class="ghost">|</span>
        <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=ca&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">Canada</a>
    </div>"""

root = html.fromstring(html_string)
print(root.xpath('//a[@itemprop="url"]//text()'))
```

Which will also result in :

```
['USA', 'Canada']
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple method **`findAll`** can be used to extract the Country names alone.
Here is the solution code in Python 3:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ="""
<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
    <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=us&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">USA</a>
    <span class="ghost">|</span>
    <a href="/search/title?country_of_origin=ca&amp;ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">Canada</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for i in soup.findAll("a"):
    print(i.text)
```

The execution of the above code will give you the desired result:

```
USA
Canada
```